How to find distinguish between pools and markets for newly created token transaction
I have an output of my parsed transaction from signatures of newly created spl tokens. From the json output, how is it possible to find the pool1, pool2, and market of the token as it is displayed in solscan: I tried locating them in the same position assuming they were hardcoded. But you can notice for example:
the following are pool creation signatures:
signature 'rrwBtJEhSMdsMzV3ebr3HfnEqyqKzcTffW5QyT1nMjqBnt5jh8Acor9HAoNKstVegryERcirbALKKF6jEsDUGQz' and signature '5EV5QC76xhA7ic5aUXyReVK5RRYsM6L3MDpxSQU2eDkXixrtFHYkt4jdo2EFnNErcqzXENVc45YXtnQcu3DnKBTN'
for example sig1:
{
"jsonrpc":"2.0",
"result":{
"blockTime":1727812401,
"meta":{},
"slot":293135132,
"transaction":{
"message":{
"accountKeys":[
"39azUYFWPz3VHgKCf3VChUwbpURdCHRxjWVowf5jUJjg",
"4Knt1PL6Lsi4Kd14QyUQVU89u4D8etiYz5TVVCGv6art",
"7CnQMfRP4oWjBaLZj4YGrVH5x1dkPzv6cuNgwagvXWAT",
"E2d2VMpLoWiXtTr924X8x5QY9aKjBs5fN5T3vZqFM5jC",
"B9SxusmH7ifH7zPb3D5ptq2SHNtiPjr1VXM3cEBz7Wo4",
"7ZWCN7jN3VeeWXGQnck6Rwq6dwyJ8dJZXZL35uX5Nscn",
"51uH6Bs7XkoF3snY6itaR3MbfLzjutzFtfSRJ7AA89mc",
"9jeiuegevTR7JrGKbcbPy4SghE78KZe7ZtQVu3gcMJBY",
"7YttLkHDoNj9wyDur5pM1ejNaAvT9X4eqaYcHQqtj2G5",
"AR6Me9jhoqFjQRm8it81Gs82LvUrjw2hXu4EiJGyye6A",
"xrGxaSgGgshwZfQur59WjEoJrSqAg5hfPYa4en6wvYm",
"ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
"11111111111111111111111111111111",
"TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
"So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
"SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111",
"675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8",
"ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL",
"5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
"HVqkGQhJZdL1NK15TCipwooDV7TQ1mSfjfUW6fMBpump",
"9DCxsMizn3H1hprZ7xWe6LDzeUeZBksYFpBWBtSf1PQX",
"srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX",
"9x1512mht9CSH2TPVvzg8c5xR9CejTepQzBMeSDRjtMV"
],
sig2:
{
"jsonrpc":"2.0",
"result":{
"blockTime":1728070769,
"meta":{},
"slot":293705683,
"transaction":{
"message":{
"accountKeys":[
"CQ4mjHVYtN2277QykfSrZGPeo26QUxCy9kfxRNFN3VgF",
"abKYbS3fxjx1vgnhfAkWaFgHggMksSAFmFxp8FFBVFw",
"3jF4yc718mNWcmuWfZjhcxKqKUFnE3S943w4QiMDETvX",
"3tmtddbWcaH1z7cqS2uvPhS8Rxs727anBhAibnsrVzCN",
"7YttLkHDoNj9wyDur5pM1ejNaAvT9X4eqaYcHQqtj2G5",
"7anGGX13KCNKRZGxod2bUDzcY48sWfAvcD5RxUd8cMKM",
"84jVDpEstaiZzDAhih3PoiXpzcaV3HKGsTh5PtsJJR2X",
"8X5mX3NZt2bn8qd3AK97YNBK8HH2FKxpabnBmVYTEVMP",
"CRQNmTUXLzpDPCHtK11oqY7mEYpZr8U1gCwcGi26HmKF",
"DsLmxbiLMsKGW7enDythSSgXa6yAnnfph8Ybc2tC5hEu",
"FKRbgnAphK7zEWBrPxrQFpymmR7pMWgwi76uKTLciDZR",
"GfMv9DjRsMjXt187pSKJbbYScNLjfPfFYUQceijwUML4",
"11111111111111111111111111111111",
"So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
"SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111",
"TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
"srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX",
"5CfRRdBrNUXaVzCojqCWEh3b1uusG1E3MGCiLhoQpump",
"5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
"675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8",
"9DCxsMizn3H1hprZ7xWe6LDzeUeZBksYFpBWBtSf1PQX",
"ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL"
],
"addressTableLookups":[
],
have pools and market accounts in different location when it comes to the parsed json. i highlighted pool1 7ZWCN7jN3VeeWXGQnck6Rwq6dwyJ8dJZXZL35uX5Nscn and GfMv9DjRsMjXt187pSKJbbYScNLjfPfFYUQceijwUML4 of each signature and they are indeed in different locations...
How can i consistently distinguish these accounts in newly created spl token transactions? Am i going about it the wrong way?
Thanks
